# my form is holding data even when i am not clicking submit button.but if i am refreshing my form it fine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

This is my form

```
<form name="userForm" data-ng-submit="updateUserProfile(userForm.$valid)" class="signin form-horizontal" validate-form="" autocomplete="off">
    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="firstName" required name="firstName" maxlength="25" class="form-control" data-ng-model="user.firstName" placeholder="First Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="lastName" required name="lastName" maxlength="25" class="form-control" data-ng-model="user.lastName" placeholder="Last Name">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email">Email</label>
            <input type="email" id="email" required name="email" maxlength="150" class="form-control" data-ng-model="user.email" placeholder="Email">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="username">Username</label>
            <input type="text" id="username" required name="username" maxlength="25" class="form-control" data-ng-model="user.username" placeholder="Username">
        </div>
        <div class="text-center form-group mt">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Save Profile</button>
        </div>
        <div data-ng-show="success" class="text-center text-success">
            <strong>Profile Saved Successfully</strong>
        </div>
        <div data-ng-show="error" class="text-center text-danger">
            <strong data-ng-bind="error"></strong>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

now when I click edit profile in my ui and suppose editing my name but not submitting it and navigating to some other part of the app. but when I am coming back to edit profile it is showing edited version. not the original

this is my controller function.

```
$scope.updateUserProfile = function(isValid) {          
    if (isValid) {
        $scope.success = $scope.error = null;
        var user = new Users($scope.user);

        user.$update(function(response) {
            $scope.success = true;
            Authentication.user = response;
        }, function(response) {
            $scope.error = response.data.message;
        });
    } else {
        $scope.submitted = false;
    }
};
```

please help me as fast ,I have to complete it

Comment: ng-model attribute results in  two way binding.When you update the view the model behind also gets updated.Unless you refresh the page the model holds the values the view has edited, using two way binding.To workaround this issue reassign the model to original values on form load

Comment: yup doing refreshing it getting its old value, but i dont want my value to change without submitting it. can you explain more ?like how to reassign my model, please

Comment: Ok ,here where do you assign the user object?

Comment: Also post your service or your other code, where you get the $scope.user data from to help better..

Comment: assigning user is in different file. in this controler i have scope for update my  account and reset password. means it has nothing to do while creating user.  while updating as you can see that in form tag it is calling updateUserProfile(userForm.$valid)  scope in my controler on submit which is like this angular.module('users').controller('SettingsController',

Answer (score 0):

That is happening because the properties haven't been instantiated.
You can set the values in your java script inside the controller whenever this particular page loads like this

```
user.firstName="";
user.lastName=""
user.email=""
user.username=""
```

Comment: i have added controler above in my code, if i am initializing what you said, it still not working. can you help me little more :)

Comment: Are these properties in controller scope or in $ scope,once you find out that you will have to do something like this,

Comment: if in controller,

Comment: is user in user.firstname the controller alias,if so you can use the code i have mentioned,
else if ng-model is in $scope then the code should be like this,
$scope.user.firstname=""

Comment: if you are not sure about your scope please paste the controller code for the above form,i will check and let you know where the above code should be defined.

Comment: From the js code you have mentioned above it looks as if you are using the $scope so you can use the below code,but it should not be given within any particular function,instead it should be given inside the controller part,
$scope.user.firstName="";
$scope.user.lastName="";
$scope.user.email="";
$scope.user.username="";

Comment: if i will do as you are saying, i will get blank field. suppose i am user and if i put $scope.user.firstName=""; then if i will refresh my page it will hold blank value.  in this controler i have scope for update my account and reset password. means it has nothing to do while creating user(thats is in another file). while updating as you can see that in form tag it is calling updateUserProfile(userForm.$valid) scope in my controler on submit ,and in this controler i am having  $scope.updateUserProfile = function(isValid) {          
    if (isValid) {
        some implementation
};

Comment: are these properties in the $scope being used throughout the application?

Comment: yes. as you can see in data-ng-model i am using user.firstName. means i have created user some where else in the app but wanted to update in this controler.

Comment: Then it will be better you don't initialize any of the ng-models to "" as the $scope is going to have the data for a single user,instead maybe you can set a $scope variable to true when submit happens and else false and if it is false then you can set the ng-models to the original values.you will have to save the original values in some variables
for ex:
$scope.submit=true;
if($scope.submit){
--Set the new values to the $scope variables--
}
else{
--Set the old values to the $scope variables--
}

Comment: i think you need not bother about the new values part since only after the submit will the new values be set.

Comment: i think you are still confuse with my question, everything is working fine except while page loading my value is not getting to its orignal value in the UI. (loading in angular.js means rout change). if i am refreshing my page its getting its old value but not on page loading. please review my question once again

Comment: when you load the page you have written some code right to get the model values,if you can set the those values you get on loading ,into the ng-model at the time of routing i.e. maybe you can try it through the service function.

Comment: Can you place the code for the controller for this page and also routing code?